Draw onto image, then show and save result
This is what I want to do:

Read in an image from disk (pngs in my case)
Draw some shapes into it, like rectangles, ...
Display the resulting image in my jupyter notebook and also save it back to file

I'm currently using matplotlib for the drawing part. The issue: This process does not preserve resolution. The resulting png written to file is scaled by some random amount. As far as I understand, this is because matplotlib is using physical units and everything is dependent on screen size etc. That's a problem for me because I want to have pixel perfect drawing of the shapes and draw/save the image in the exact same resolution. I'm beginning to think that matplotlib might not be the right tool for what I want to do.
Any advice? Below is the code I am currently using.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.patches as patches

# Read the image.
image_path = 'input_image.png'
output_image_path = 'output_image.png'
image = mpimg.imread(image_path)

# Create a figure.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.axis('off')

# Create a rectangle patch and add it.
rect = patches.Rectangle((100, 100), 20, 20, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.imshow(image)

# Save result.
plt.savefig(output_image_path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)

# Input image: (1200x800)
# Output image: (496x330)


You might want to google how to do this with opencv, this is not the correct way of doing this. What you are doing is plotting and then saving the plot. You want to use opencv functions like cv2.rectangle, cv2.circle and so on...

There is nothing wrong with your code. It is the inadequate functionality provided by the python libraries you are using that is responsible for the undesired output. Therefore, I would recommend you to use PIL library that preserves the image resolution. I tried to rewrite the above code using the PIL library and verified as there is not substantial loss in the resolution.
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the image.
image_path = 'sunset.jpeg' #Change this to your own image
output_image_path = 'sunset_output_image.jpeg'
image = Image.open(image_path)

# Draw shapes using Pillow's ImageDraw.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.rectangle([100, 100, 320, 320], outline="red")  # Draw a rectangle with top-left corner at (100, 100) and bottom-right corner at (320, 320)

# Save the modified image using Pillow to preserve resolution.
image.save(output_image_path)

# Display the image in the Jupyter notebook.
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')  # Hide axes
plt.show()

And here is the output that shows a rectangle on the actual image without any loss of resolution.
